# Calculating/Averaging/Aggregating Effect Size Across Multiple Measurements

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size, measurement, aggregation, cohens-d

What is the standard practice for calculating a total effect size (using Cohen's d) across multiple measurements in one study? Do you calculate the effect size for each measurement and then take the average effect size?

Below are the data sets--there are two tables, two groups (AH [control group] and SA), each table has four post-test measurements ("measurement", "fluency", "syntactic complexity", "lexical complexity", "accuracy"):

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe that the different effect sizes would be weighted before combining them. Try searching for "combining weighted effect sizes" or something similar.